# HandlerChanged to (httpPlatformHandlerMain) issue in Azure

Tags: azure

I was running a web app service and all of a sudden I see a degraded performance in the response time. I did not do code changes but I get the followin warning:

`We analyzed 15 slow request(s) and identified module(s) consuming most of the time are - HandlerChanged to (httpPlatformHandlerMain)(95.83%)`

I did not explicitly change any configuration on Azure so thats why I am suprised to see such degraded service.

I redeployed the same code and restarted the webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be several reasons for degraded performance in your **Azure Web App Service**, such as increased traffic, changes in modifying infrastructure.

Follow the below steps to troubleshoot **Azure Web App Performance** issue.

1. **Check the resource utilization:** Kindly check the **Azure Web App** utilization such as **CPU**, **Memory**, and **Disk Space**.

[image]

If your **Web App** utilization is high, you may need to scale up your **App Service plan**, Like below.

[image]

3. **Check the Web Application logs:** Kindly check if any error messages in the logs that could indicate the cause of the issue. You can check the logs in the **Azure portal** by navigating to below options.

**Azure Portal > Select your App Service > Log stream**

[image]

3. **Monitor your app performance:** Monitor the performance of your Azure Web App by sending Apps Logs to **Log Analytics workspace** to get a better understanding of the App performance degradation issues,

**Azure Portal > Select your App Service >  Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting**

[image]

4. You can check for recent changes in your application., such as changes to the **code** & **configuration**, to see if they are causing any **performance** issues in your application.
5. **Restart the App Service:** Sometimes you can resolve the Azure App performance issues by restarting the application.

**Azure Portal > App Service > Select your application > Overview > Restart**

[image]

For more information refer :  [Troubleshoot slow app performance issues in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation)